# trigger onmouseup element correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following html structure:

```
 <div id="grandparent">
    <div id="parent">
            <p>
                high light me with mouse!! highlight me with mouse!!highlight me with mouse!!

            </p>

</div>
</div>
```

And I have this js code:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (event) {
        var target=event.target;
        target=$(target);
        var parent = target.parent();
        console.log(parent.parent().attr("id"));
            if (window.getSelection) {
            var selection = window.getSelection();
            selectedText = selection.toString();
                console.log(selectedText);
            }
        });
```

So this piece of code just console logs selected text.

But I have  a problem - when I click not on my `<p>` element and just on document - and then I move mouse to select text holding left button I can't get the id of parent div because

```
var target=event.target;
```

target becomes document element

Comment: why not `$("p").mouseup` ?

Answer (score 0):

Change `$(document).mouseup(` for `$("#parent").mouseup(` .

Code:

```js
$("#parent").mouseup(function (event) {
  var target=event.target;
  target=$(target);
  var parent = target.parent();
  console.log(parent.parent().attr("id"));
  if (window.getSelection) {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    selectedText = selection.toString();
    console.log(selectedText);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="grandparent">
    <div id="parent">
            <p>
                high light me with mouse!! highlight me with mouse!!highlight me with mouse!!

            </p>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know $("#parent") it is dynamically created